# Can an object of a generic class be created with any type, T?

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, types

I learnt basic idea about generic class is one that can be parameterized with another class
(or type). The example I am given is `ArrayList<E>`.

Does generic class specifically refer to `ArrayList`, or any type?

Comment: There are many generic classes.  Any class declared with `<` after its name is a generic class.  There many examples in the [java.util package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html). There are plenty of others in other packages as well.

Comment: The possible type arguments for a given type parameter are determined by its bound. See for example https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Answer (score 1):

**All classes declared with** `< .. >` **are generic classes.**

An ArrayList of some given type `T` is declared as:

```
ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>()
```

ArrayList holding Integers (when intending to hold `int`) should be

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>()
```

You can also make your own generic classes (here is a Node for some singly-linked list holding some unspecified type `E`)

```
class Node<E> {
    private E element;
    private Node<E> next;

    public Node(E element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public E getElement() {
        return this.element;
    }

    public Node<E> getNext() {
        return this.next;
    }
}
```

Note: `T` cannot be a primitive type such as `char`, `int`, `boolean`, `double`. You have to use wrappers such as `Character`, `Integer`, `Boolean`, or `Double`.

Comment: Does T mean any type including primitive type and reference type?

Comment: T *cannot* be a primitive type. Instead, use wrapper types.

Comment: then E is a smaller type than T?

Comment: E is not a smaller type than T. Like T, E cannot be a primitive.

The notation `T` and `E` are just conventions meaning an unspecified class. `T` stands for "type", `E` stands for "element of that Type (T)`

Comment: `T` represents any non-primitive type. Just remember that your `ArrayList<E>` is of *unspecified type* `E`. `T`, `E`, are used when creating your own generic types.

Answer (score 0):

Generics in Java is similar to templates in C++. The idea is to allow type (Integer, String, … etc and user defined types) to be a parameter to methods, classes and interfaces. For example, classes like HashSet, ArrayList, HashMap, etc use generics very well. We can use them for any type.

**Generic Class:**

To create objects of generic class, we use following syntax.

// To create an instance of generic class 
BaseType  obj = new BaseType ()

**Note: In Parameter type we can not use primitives like 
      'int','char' or 'double'.**

```
// A Simple Java program to show working of user defined
// Generic classes

// We use < > to specify Parameter type
class Test<T>
{
    // An object of type T is declared
    T obj;
    Test(T obj) {  this.obj = obj;  }  // constructor
    public T getObject()  { return this.obj; }
}

// Driver class to test above
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // instance of Integer type
        Test <Integer> iObj = new Test<Integer>(15);
        System.out.println(iObj.getObject());

        // instance of String type
        Test <String> sObj =
                          new Test<String>("GeeksForGeeks");
        System.out.println(sObj.getObject());
    }
}
```

We can also pass multiple Type parameters in Generic classes.

```
// A Simple Java program to show multiple
// type parameters in Java Generics

// We use < > to specify Parameter type
class Test<T, U>
{
    T obj1;  // An object of type T
    U obj2;  // An object of type U

    // constructor
    Test(T obj1, U obj2)
    {
        this.obj1 = obj1;
        this.obj2 = obj2;
    }

    // To print objects of T and U
    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println(obj1);
        System.out.println(obj2);
    }
}

// Driver class to test above
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Test <String, Integer> obj =
            new Test<String, Integer>("GfG", 15);

        obj.print();
    }
}
```

**Generic Functions:**

We can also write generic functions that can be called with different types of arguments based on the type of arguments passed to generic method, the compiler handles each method.

```
// A Simple Java program to show working of user defined
// Generic functions

class Test
{
    // A Generic method example
    static <T> void genericDisplay (T element)
    {
        System.out.println(element.getClass().getName() +
                           " = " + element);
    }

    // Driver method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         // Calling generic method with Integer argument
        genericDisplay(11);

        // Calling generic method with String argument
        genericDisplay("GeeksForGeeks");

        // Calling generic method with double argument
        genericDisplay(1.0);
    }
}
```

**Advantages of Generics:**

Programs that uses Generics has got many benefits over non-generic code.

```
Code Reuse: We can write a method/class/interface once and use for any type we want.

.
Type Safety : Generics make errors to appear compile time than at run time (It’s always better to know problems in your code at compile time rather than making your code fail at run time). Suppose you want to create an ArrayList that store name of students and if by mistake programmer adds an integer object instead of string, compiler allows it. But, when we retrieve this data from ArrayList, it causes problems at runtime.


     // A Simple Java program to demonstrate that NOT using
        // generics can cause run time exceptions
        import java.util.*;

        class Test
        {
            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                // Creatinga an ArrayList without any type specified
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

                al.add("Sachin");
                al.add("Rahul");
                al.add(10); // Compiler allows this

                String s1 = (String)al.get(0);
                String s2 = (String)al.get(1);

                // Causes Runtime Exception
                String s3 = (String)al.get(2);
            }
        }

Output :

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
   java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

How generics solve this problem?
    At the time of defining ArrayList, we can specify that this list can take only String objects.
    // Using generics converts run time exceptions into 
    // compile time exception.
    import java.util.*;

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a an ArrayList with String specified
        ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList<String> ();

        al.add("Sachin");
        al.add("Rahul");

        // Now Compiler doesn't allow this
        al.add(10); 

        String s1 = (String)al.get(0);
        String s2 = (String)al.get(1);
        String s3 = (String)al.get(2);
    }
}

Output:

15: error: no suitable method found for add(int)
        al.add(10); 
          ^
```

.
Individual Type Casting is not needed: If we do not use generics, then, in the above example every-time we retrieve data from ArrayList, we have to typecast it. Typecasting at every retrieval operation is a big headache. If we already know that our list only holds string data then we need not to typecast it every time.

```
// We don't need to typecast individual members of ArrayList
import java.util.*;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating a an ArrayList with String specified
        ArrayList <String> al = new ArrayList<String> ();

        al.add("Sachin");
        al.add("Rahul");

        // Typecasting is not needed 
        String s1 = al.get(0);
        String s2 = al.get(1);
    }
}
```

.
Implementing generic algorithms: By using generics, we can implement algorithms that work on different types of objects and at the same they are type safe too.